# Adding html tags with regex/python, sub code not working

Tags: python, html, regex

So I have an assignment where I need to add HTML tags to a poem, and I want each line to have a paragraph tag with a class ID. I have made the code, but when I print it, it doesn't show.

I have made a regex (re) sub for each line that starts again when the line is an empty list item. I then print the list after the loop, but it looks the same as before the loop. Why is that?

I have also tried the first part of the sub on regex101, so it should catch the entire sentence. The second should sub with everything in the sentence, but add the p tags. \1 is used to refer back to the (.+)

```
textList = text.split("\n")

sentenceCount = 0

for sentence in textList:
    if sentence == "":
        sentenceCount = 0
    elif sentenceCount == 0:
        sentence = re.sub(r"^(.+)$", r"<p class=\"a\">\1</p>", sentence)
        sentenceCount += 1
    elif sentenceCount == 1:
        sentence = re.sub(r"^(.+)$", r"<p class=\"b\">\1</p>", sentence)
        sentenceCount += 1
    elif sentenceCount == 2:
        sentence = re.sub(r"^(.+)$", r"<p class=\"a\">\1</p>", sentence)
        sentenceCount += 1
    elif sentenceCount == 3:
        sentence = re.sub(r"^(.+)$", r"<p class=\"b\">\1</p>", sentence)
        sentenceCount += 1
    elif sentenceCount == 4:
        sentence = re.sub(r"^(.+)$", r"<p class=\"b\">\1</p>", sentence)
        sentenceCount += 1
    elif sentenceCount == 5:
        sentence = re.sub(r"^(.+)$", r"<p class=\"c\">\1</p>", sentence)
        sentenceCount += 1
    elif sentenceCount == 6:
        sentence = re.sub(r"^(.+)$", r"<p class=\"c\">\1</p>", sentence)
        sentenceCount += 1

print(textList)
```

This is the part of the code for this problem. The textList variable works fine, the problem is with the for loop somewhere.

Comment: The list looks the same because you never change it? Why would you *expect* it to look any different after the loop?

Comment: Since i substitute each element of the list with what is in the list + the tags. At least thats what I am trying to do, like I said in the post..If I forgot something obvious, please tell me.

Comment: Secondly. `WHAT IS YOUR INPUT` what is your expected output?

Comment: Duplicate: [Can't modify list elements in a loop Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/19290762)

Comment: My input is a sentence. Any sentence. What is in the sentence doesn't matter. The expected output is also said in the post. The inputted sentence with parapgrah tags around them..

Comment: the variable sentence, when reassigned, does not affect the original list that it came from. Is it just being assigned values one by one from the list, but itself is just a name. if you reassign, you break that linkage. The original list is not affected. However, note that you should not care about affecting the original list in the first place. create an empty `result` list, and start appending values to it inside the loop.

Comment: No. I mean post it. Regex is pattern based so it is hard to `accurately` make a regex without seeing what you're building against. There are usually several nuances to take into consideration when making regexes outside of what someone `describes` usually considers

Comment: FailSafe: Each list element is a totally different sentence, my regex is trying to capture the ENTIRE sentence/list-element. The input pattern I am trying to get is EVERYTHING. The resulting pattern I want is EVERYTHING with the exact tags I have written in the post. Do you still want me to write down every line of a long poem and then the tags I want around each one? I am not sure what you are asking me to post, and for what reason..

Comment: And that is the mark of inexperience. Sometimes I might want to know if I want to process the poem in multiline mode or as a full string. Sometimes I might want to know if punctuation marks are involved. Sometimes I might want to know how many newline characters separate stanzas. You can post 5 lines, or the lines that show the delimiters for a stanza. But honestly, it looks like this has been marked as a duplicate (although I'm not totally sure that it should be because there isn't specific input to compare to desired output). Someone else saw fit to '+1' this so there might be disagreement

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, how do I append valies to it?

Comment: @FailSafe, dude, input = blablablablablablabla, desired output = <p class ="a or b or c">blablablablablablabla</p>, for each list element. That was my question. And yes, I am inexperienced, but I gave the relevant information for the issue I had. The things you talk about are not about what I was asking. They might be helpful, but not relevant to my spesific issue.

Comment: Here's my smart-alecky response. `re.sub(r'(?m)([\S]+)', r'<p class ="a or b or c">\1</p>', input)`. That will work for what you posted, but will not work properly if there are any spaces or newline characters. I'm literally trying to help you, help me, help you. The offense you're taking isn't necessary. I've had to revise so many regexes in the past on several answers because of descriptions that didn't account for nuances which is why I asked for specific input and desired output so I knew exactly what to do.

Comment: @FailSafe, I apologize for the harshness I responded with, but as I said, the relevant information was given, and Paritosh answered with the relevant response. The issue is now solved. If I had an issue with a more specific regex, I would have written the input and desired output in more detail.

Comment: Happy to hear the issue was solved.

Comment: And  I'm glad you are trying to help. It's much appreciated. :)